# NSwagStudio Liquid templates

Tags: asp.net-core

How do you use liquid templates with NSwagStudio to change how files are generated?

Comment: I asked a related question re: gaining access to Swagger/OAS 3.0 json from Templates at [Extension point or access to OpenApiDocument from Liquid Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304352/extension-point-or-access-to-openapidocument-from-liquid-template).  If you have information it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

OK, it seems there are some samples of liquid templates there:
https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/tree/master/src/NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp/Templates

You can copy them and start editing them.

Then, you just need to point to your folder to use them to generate custom code.

There is a wiki:
https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/Templates

Comment: Dumb question: Any idea how to put a line break in these liquid templates?

Comment: Another dump question: How do I stop using these templates? My requirments have changed and I don't need this templates anymore, but I get this error that says "template path is required" when I blank out the field.

Comment: The original value for `templateDirectory` was just null.