# Extension point or access to OpenApiDocument from Liquid Template

Tags: angular, code-generation, nswag, njsonschema, nswagstudio

We have [Specification Extensions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#specification-extensions) (i.e. `x-isPrimaryKey`) in our generated `OpenApiDocument` and need to add them as `ClassDecorators` to our Angular models.

e.g. We communicate if is Pk, Fk and property level permissions.

I am successfully overriding the [File.liquid](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.CodeGeneration.TypeScript/Templates/File.liquid) to customize the generated models.

I have explored the [TypeScriptFileTemplateModel](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.CodeGeneration.TypeScript/Models/TypeScriptFileTemplateModel.cs) but `_document` is `private`.

Any help with discoverability of Template Variables for `.Liquid` files is appreciated.

Specifically, is there an extension point to be able to read OAS 3 `components` -> `schemas` from any `.Liquid` template to extend model generation with?